# Cannot boot in windows 10 after installing Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, dual-boot

So I have just my new pc and decided to dual boot Windows and Linux, one for games one for programming (I know I can learn programming in Windows but I want to become familiar with the terminal).

Anyways after installing Fedora alongside Windows I couldn't see Windows in grub so I searched a bit and made it visible. However, when I try to boot it, it says boot files missing or have some error. So I decided to reinstall Windows completely on same the partition where it was (formatted of course) and still cannot get into windows but Linux works just fine.

I edited the `40_custom` file in `/etc/grub.d` and it still does not work. I have searched a lot and couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.